# Alias For partition table SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4, t1.col5

from (tab1.tab1_1 partition(p20191231)) t1 

LEFT JOIN ( 
            select t2.col_1 AS col_1, t2.col_2
            from (tab2.tab2_2  partition (p20191231)) t2
            where date between '1-Dec-2019' and '31-Dec-2019')
            ON t1.col1 = col_1
where 
        t1.col6 between '1-Dec-2019' AND '31-Dec-2019';
```

I am trying to join 2 table where both tables are partition table. It takes time but the output is not joining result. It is only showing the first table data. Is it for alias for partition table ?How we can use alias for partition table ??

Comment: I can see that both the partition used here has same names. Is it a mistake or intentional?

Comment: intentional, tab1.tab1_1 partition(p20191231), tab2.tab2_2  partition (p20191231) are two different table same date partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo didn't call any columns from 2nd table (t2). You may follow below code

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4, t1.col5,t2.col_1,t2.col_2
from tab1.tab1_1 partition(p20191231) t1 
LEFT JOIN ( 
            select t2.col_1 AS col_1, t2.col_2
            from (tab2.tab2_2  partition (p20191231)) t2
            where date between '1-Dec-2019' and '31-Dec-2019') t2
            ON t1.col1 = col_1
where 
        t1.col6 between '1-Dec-2019' AND '31-Dec-2019';
```

or even simplified by

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4, t1.col5,t2.col_1,t2.col_2
from 
  tab1.tab1_1 partition(p20191231) t1, 
  tab2.tab2_2  partition(p20191231) t2
where 
  t2.date between '1-Dec-2019' and '31-Dec-2019' and
  t1.col1 = col_1 and 
  t1.col6 between '1-Dec-2019' AND '31-Dec-2019';
```